# Pyramid app "Header names must be latin1 string" AssertionError from WebTest

Tags: python, pyramid, wsgi, webtest

How can I deal with a "Header names must be latin1 string" `AssertionError` from WebTest that occurs when Pyramid apps are run in Python 2 with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`?

We're in the process of migrating our Pyramid app from Python 2 to 3, and added `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to all our Python files, and this caused the following error from WebTest in Python 2:

```
AssertionError: Header names must be latin1 string (not Py2 unicode or Py3 bytes type).
```

Here's a [full traceback](https://gist.github.com/seanh/1e8bee4476eca4d7f29e4c8d62f01171) in case anyone's interested, though I don't think it's very enlightening.

The `AssertionError` is raised whenever your app sets any response header. For example this line would trigger it:

```
response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
```

Since we have `unicode_literals` those string literals are unicode strings in Python 2, whereas before `unicode_literals` they would have been byte strings, that's why adding `unicode_literals` triggered the `AssertionError` from WebTest.

In Python 3 no error occurs.

The reason WebTest has this `AssertionError` is that https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333 requires HTTP response headers to be native strings - byte strings in Python 2 and unicode strings in Python 3. Here's the WebTest issue and pull request that added the assert:

https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/issues/119
https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/pull/180

`b`-prefixing the strings like `response.headers[b"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = b"*"` would get rid of the `AssertionError` in Python 2 but cause the error to appear if the tests were run in Python 3.

Wrapping the strings in `str()` like `response.headers[str("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")] = str("*")` will fix it in both Python 2 and 3, but requires you to find and `str()`-wrap every response header string throughout your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a tween that `str()`-wraps all response headers seems to be a good fix:

```
def encode_headers_tween_factory(handler, registry):
    def encode_headers_tween(request):
        resp = handler(request)
        for key in resp.headers.keys():
            values = resp.headers.getall(key)
            del resp.headers[key]
            for value in values:
                resp.headers.add(str(key), str(value))
        return resp
    return encode_headers_tween

config.add_tween('h.tweens.encode_headers_tween_factory')
```

Then you can simply remove this tween once you no longer need to support Python 2.

Comment: The `str()` calls here will crash if any response header keys or values contain non-ASCII characters, but in our app we don't have any of those (and I'm not sure whether they'd be valid in WSGI or HTTP if we did).